# Unable to solve Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, awt-eventqueue

I am currently creating a payroll software and the RemoveEmployee class does not function due to an error. I tried working my way backwards to resolve the issue but I was unable to due to my lack of experience in java.

```
package Assigment;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author dj_sp
 */
public class RemoveEmployee extends javax.swing.JFrame {
File sallaried=new File("Salaried Employee Registration.txt");  
File hourly=new File("Hourly Employee Registration.txt");
File commission=new File("Commission Employee Registration.txt");
//creating  a text files

    /**
     * Creates new form RemoveEmployee
     */
    public RemoveEmployee() {
       initComponents();
       removeSalEmp();                             
       removeHourlyEmp();
       removeCommissionEmp();
        //calling methods
       }

    public void removeSemp(){

       }
       public void removeSalEmp(){
        DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)tblSalaried.getModel();

        FileReader fr;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(sallaried);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);                               
                 //reading from text file
             String line;
             int column;
             int row=0;

        while(( line=br.readLine())!=null){
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(line,row,0);
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,1);
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,2);
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,3);
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,4);
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,5);
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,6);                                     
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,7);
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,8);
   tblSalaried.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,9);

            row++;
             //sets to a jtable
}


            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

       public void removeHourlyEmp(){
DefaultTableModel table =(DefaultTableModel)tblSalaried.getModel();

        FileReader fr;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(hourly);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

             String line;
             int column;
             int row=0;

        while(( line=br.readLine())!=null){
   tblHourly.setValueAt(line,row,0);
   tblHourly.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,1);
   tblHourly.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,2);
   tblHourly.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,3);
   tblHourly.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,4);
   tblHourly.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,5);
   tblHourly.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,6);
   tblHourly.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,7);
   tblHourly.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,8);



            row++;

}


            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       }


    public void removeCommissionEmp(){
           DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)tblCommission.getModel();

        FileReader fr;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(commission);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

             String line;
             int column;
             int row=0;

        while(( line=br.readLine())!=null){
   tblCommission.setValueAt(line,row,0);
   tblCommission.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,1);
   tblCommission.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,2);
   tblCommission.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,3);
   tblCommission.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,4);
   tblCommission.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,5);
   tblCommission.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,6);
   tblCommission.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,7);
   tblCommission.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,8);
   tblCommission.setValueAt(br.readLine(),row,9);


            row++;

}


            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       }
/**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content ofs("unchecked")
     *  */
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         



        DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)tblSalaried.getModel();
        int selectedRow=tblSalaried.getSelectedRow();

        int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to remove selected employee");
        //displays confirmation dialog to user
    if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
         model.removeRow(selectedRow);
        //gets the user answer and if true removes employee from table


         String newwFile = "Salaried Employee Registration2.txt";
         //creating new text file
        File newFile = new File(newwFile);
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newFile);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            int rowCount=tblSalaried.getRowCount();
            for(int i = 0; i < tblSalaried.getRowCount(); i++){//rows
                for(int j = 0; j < tblSalaried.getColumnCount(); j++){//columns
                  //

                   if(tblSalaried.getValueAt(i,j)!=null){
                    bw.write((String) tblSalaried.getValueAt(i,j));
                    bw.newLine();
                   }
                    //writing to a file while jtable is nt equal to nothing
                }


            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee has been removed from the system");
            //display a message to user 
            bw.close();
            fw.close();

            sallaried.delete();
            newFile.renameTo(sallaried);
            //deletes old file,
            // renames new file to the old file



        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }else
    {

    }



    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        MainMenu FirstMenu=new MainMenu();
        MainMenu.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)tblHourly.getModel();
        int selectedRow=tblHourly.getSelectedRow();

          int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to remove selected employee");
          if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
               model.removeRow(selectedRow);


         String newwFile = "Hourly Employee Registration2.txt";
        File newFile = new File(newwFile);
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newFile);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            int rowCount=tblHourly.getRowCount();
            for(int i = 0; i < tblHourly.getRowCount(); i++){//rows
                for(int j = 0; j < tblHourly.getColumnCount(); j++){//columns


                   if(tblHourly.getValueAt(i,j)!=null){
                    bw.write((String) tblHourly.getValueAt(i,j));
                    bw.newLine();
                   }

                }


            }
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee has been removed from the system");

            bw.close();
            fw.close();

            hourly.delete();
            newFile.renameTo(hourly);



        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
          }

    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)tblCommission.getModel();
        int selectedRow=tblCommission.getSelectedRow();

        int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to remove selected employee");
          if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                model.removeRow(selectedRow);


         String newwFile = "Commission Employee Registration2.txt";
        File newFile = new File(newwFile);
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newFile);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            int rowCount=tblCommission.getRowCount();
            for(int i = 0; i < tblCommission.getRowCount(); i++){//rows
                for(int j = 0; j < tblCommission.getColumnCount(); j++){//columns


                   if(tblCommission.getValueAt(i,j)!=null){
                    bw.write((String) tblCommission.getValueAt(i,j));
                    bw.newLine();
                   }

                }


            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee has been removed from the system");

            bw.close();
            fw.close();

            commission.delete();
            newFile.renameTo(commission);




        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
          }

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RemoveEmployee.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RemoveEmployee().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator3;
    private javax.swing.JTable tblCommission;
    private javax.swing.JTable tblHourly;
    private javax.swing.JTable tblSalaried;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The error message I am receiving. All of my other classes are functioning except this one. I tried re-initialising the  constructors but nothing helped.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Assigment.RemoveEmployee.removeSalEmp(RemoveEmployee.java:47)
    at Assigment.RemoveEmployee.<init>(RemoveEmployee.java:37)
    at Assigment.RemoveEmployee$1.run(RemoveEmployee.java:376)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);    -- is throwing.. so file file reader most likely is null   -- Check your path

Comment: #2) generally file handle is closed in finally block

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, I don't see where you assign a value to `tblSalaried`. It is a member of class `RemoveEmployee`. Unless you assign it a value, it is null. Hence when you try to access it, you get `NullPointerException`. And according to the code you posted, as well as the stack trace you posted, the `NullPointerException` is being thrown from this line (in method `removeSalEmp()`):

```java
DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)tblSalaried.getModel();
```

This would be line 47 in file `RemoveEmployee.java`, as stated in the stack trace you posted.

I suggest that in your `initComponents()` method you initialize class members, like `tblSalaried`. You need to add something like the following:

```java
tblSalaried = new JTable();
```

For your information, I see some other problems with your code, but I think it is better that you first discover them by yourself. You can always post another question :-)